# Sequence of number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$
$$1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,\dots$$
constructed by including the integer $2k + 1$ exactly $2k + 1$ times. Show that
$$a_n=2\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil - 1$$
for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: just find  the value of the first $a_n$ for given n,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problems are usually tackled with the help of a proof by induction; however, in the present case, the ceiling function makes it difficult to do so, that is why we have to solve it by inspection of a general case.

Let $N = 2k+1$ be an odd integer and $n_\pm$ the "bounds of appearance" of $N$ inside the sequence, i.e. $a_n = N$ for $n_- \le n \le n_+$. The upper bound, in other words, the last time $N$ appears, here denoted by $n_+$, is given by
$$
n_+ = \sum_{m \le N \\ m\,\mathrm{odd}} m = \sum_{\kappa=0}^k (2\kappa+1) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}k(k+1) + (k+1) = (k+1)^2
$$
The same reasoning permits to find $n_-$, because the first appearance of $N$ corresponds to the last position of $N-1$ plus one, hence
$$
n_- = 1 + \sum_{m < N \\ m\,\mathrm{odd}} m = 1 + \sum_{\kappa=0}^{k-1} (2\kappa+1) = 1 + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}k(k-1) + k = k^2 + 1
$$
We have thus $a_n = N = 2k+1$ when $k^2+1 \le n \le (k+1)^2$, hence $k < \sqrt{n} \le k+1$, which itself leads to $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil = k+1$ and finally $a_n = 2(\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil-1) + 1 = 2\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil - 1$. *QED.*